# Was there ever an a cappella version of Nemurihime released?

Tags: music, the-idolmaster

In episode 21 of THE iDOLM@STER, Chihaya sings Nemurihime solo at a concert. Thanks to President Kuroi's interference, the technicians won't start the music, so Chihaya decides to sing a cappella (i.e. with no accompaniment). They do start the accompaniment at the first chorus, so it doesn't stay a capella the whole way through, and furthermore the song is cut (the full duration is 5).

The video from the anime is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKIZ2RbMlOk). Note that this video contains **major spoilers**; in fact, this scene is basically the climax of the anime. In case you want to avoid any spoilers, the full version of the song from one of the CDs (with accompaniment throughout) is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf7ktJ3yYUg).

Was a full a cappella version ever released on any of the CDs, or in any other form?

[image]

Comment: The 2 YouTube videos were removed due to copyright infringement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An a capella version of this song has not been released yet.

According to [VGMdb](http://vgmdb.net/)* and [imas DB](http://imas-db.jp/song/detail/141.html), Nemurihime was only ever released on two CDs:

- **THE IDOLM@STER MASTER ARTIST 2 -FIRST SEASON- 05 Chihaya Kisaragi**: This was the original release of the song and therefore is not a special version.
- **THE IDOLM@STER ANIM@TION MASTER 07**: This is one of the many soundtracks for the anime series, but it is still the original version and is not a capella.

Note: Neither referenced site has an official relationship with the iM@S series, but they are both reliable fan-made databases.

Since the airing of the anime, Nemurihime was also released on DVD/Blu-Ray of live performances on:

- THE IDOLM@STER 7th ANNIVERSARY
- THE IDOLM@STER 6th ANNIVERSARY

However I looked up the videos of these performances and they were both the original version. I think it's safe to say that any performances of Nemurihime before the anime are also the original version.

*** Since VGMdb does not have permalink search feature, these are the parameters I used:

> trackname -- 眠り姫
>   game -- idolm@ster